# Spyder not opening in Anaconda - "Cannot import name from partially idealised module (most likely circular import)" Possible duplicate files?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

first time poster

I am using the Climada modelling tool with Spyder as my IDE of choice through Anaconda. I have created a new environment as per the Climada installation instructions and need to open Spyder to complete the final stages of the installation by running tests. Anyway...onto the problem.

I uninstalled Anaconda earlier, and then did a reinstall. Unfortunately after the reinstall Spyder was not opening in the Navigator, so I tried it through the prompt instead, and received the following message:

[**Terminal message** (apologies, reputation is not high enough to display image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M4mF.png)

I think it could be duplicate files leftover in my "AppData\Roaming" folders from my earlier uninstallation of Anaconda that is causing a few issues, but I'm not 100% sure.

Would anyone be able to confirm the problem/provide some help as to what I need to do to overcome this issue? At the moment I'm reluctant to delete any files that may need to be kept

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could try to create a new env just for Spyder and then connect to your previous env (the one you setup following the Climada instructions). For more details on this way of working with Spyder and existing envs you can check the Spyder documentation here: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment

Answer (score 0):

The conda environment for CLIMADA is known to create some issues with Spyder, although I am not sure what the exact problem with your particular issue is.
I can recommend a few things to try (also explained in the docs [here](https://climada-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/Guide_Installation.html)):
First step, deinstall spyder in the environment and then:

- Install spyder in the conda environment using pip instead of conda

```
conda activate climada_env
pip install spyder
```

- Install spyder 4 instead of 5
- Install spyder in a separate conda environment and configure it to use the climada_env (similarly as recommend by Daniel Althviz).